# Can't see other computer on network

Tags: 12.04, networking, samba, file-sharing, sftp

My friend and me are connected via LAN router, and we both have Ubuntu 12.04. There is a problem with network. My friend can see my computer on network, but I can't see his computer. I can ping him and connect to **phpmyadmin** (he has PHP server installed) but I can't access files on his computer?
What seem to be a problem?

Comment: Have you installed the `samba` package on both computers? Then reboot both computers and try again.

Comment: We did that and nothing has changed.

Comment: install package `nbtscan` and execute this command (it will try and discover connected computers): `nbtscan $(hostname -I | cut -d ' ' -f 1)/24`

Comment: Ok, I did that and it is working (program had found my friends computer ), but when I go to browse network I still can't see my friends computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments above I would:

1. check if there's a firewall of some sort that blocks connection to specific ports (if the user remembers setting up some blocking application, if it's a default install then the firewall is off by default)
2. boot from a live cd/usb and see if the problem persists.
3. try this: install the `ssh` package on both PCs, reboot, and try to connect through ssh:

   ssh remote-user@IP

(where you substitute *remote-user* with the username on the other computer and the *IP* address)

If this works, it should ask you for a password and allow you to login.

After installing ssh, you can probably use SFTP to access files on the remote system. Open nautilus, press CTRL+L, it will show the "location bar", where you type:

```
sftp://remote-user@IP
```

It should ask you for a password.